# How can creat mesh using matlab?

Tags: matlab, mesh

I want to create a strip decomposition of a square using matlab geometry tools, but I did not find anything that can help me.

Does any one have an idea of how to do it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you mean you need to create 2dplot filled with squares only?

Comment: @ Mikhail_Sam Hi, thanks for you response. I want to create a strip with two or 3 subdomains meshed with triangles, but the triangles must match at the interfaces between subdomains. Thank you a lot.